# Python3, hmac returns wrong output?! ARM71, 32bit

Tags: python, flask, hmac

I've asked another question here recently, regarding python, flask with a badsignature exception for sessions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37158432/python-flask-session-cookie-bad-signature-exception) , and I've been working with this problem now for a while, an seen another problem.

When signing a client-side session for my flask application *hmac* is used to hash the signature. On my personal computer this works fine, but when moving this to the embedded device built for this application hmac occasionally fails to hash the key (wrong output), which makes the session data invalid.

I made a small test program running the hmac.new() & .update() multiple times(10000) without any errors (on the target machine). But when the call is made inside the flask application the error occur in about 60% of the calls.

The call is made inside the "derive_key" method of itsdangerous.py and it looks like this:

```
  def derive_key(self):
        """This method is called to derive the key.  If you're unhappy with
        the default key derivation choices you can override them here.
        Keep in mind that the key derivation in itsdangerous is not intended
        to be used as a security method to make a complex key out of a short
        password.  Instead you should use large random secret keys.
        """
        salt = want_bytes(self.salt)
        if self.key_derivation == 'concat':
            return self.digest_method(salt + self.secret_key).digest()
        elif self.key_derivation == 'django-concat':
            return self.digest_method(salt + b'signer' +
                self.secret_key).digest()
        elif self.key_derivation == 'hmac':
            mac = hmac.new(self.secret_key, digestmod=self.digest_method)
            print("mac1:", binascii.hexlify(mac.digest()))  #1
            mac.update(salt)
            print("mac2:", binascii.hexlify(mac.digest()))  #2
            return mac.digest()
        elif self.key_derivation == 'none':
            return self.secret_key
        else:
            raise TypeError('Unknown key derivation method')
```

digestmod = hashlib.sha1

With the secret_key = b'testing' and salt=b'cookie-session' the expected output is:

```
mac1: b'6ab6fc891eefd3b78743ea28b1803811561a7c9b'
mac2: b'd58bd52b4ced54374ea5baca0b6aa52b0e03af74'
```

But many times these values differ. 
I've also seen that the output of mac1 & mac2 is equal! like the salt did not modify the result.

I have also asked this question here:
https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1808

This application is running on an ARM7, 32bit.
All libraries installed using yocto.

**UPDATE:**
For every call to derive_key() I also print salt and key: The output for a couple of requests is the following:

```
...: OPEN THE SESSION       OK!
...: DERIVE KEY:
...: Salt: b'cookie-session'
...: Key: b'testing'
...: mac1: b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
...: mac2: b'\xd5\x8b\xd5+L\xedT7N\xa5\xba\xca\x0bj\xa5+\x0e\x03\xaft'
...: .-.-.-.-.-.-.
...: SAVES THE SESSION      OK!
...: DERIVE KEY:
...: Salt: b'cookie-session'
...: Key: b'testing'
...: mac1: b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
...: mac2: b'\xd5\x8b\xd5+L\xedT7N\xa5\xba\xca\x0bj\xa5+\x0e\x03\xaft'
...: .-.-.-.-.-.-.
...: OPEN THE SESSION       NOT OKAY!!
...: DERIVE KEY:
...: Salt: b'cookie-session'
...: Key: b'testing'
...: mac1: b'\xc8D\xf0\x95\xc5R\x9f\xe3n\xc7\xa2 `7\xa9\xdb\xdd\xd8F\x85'
...: mac2: b'\x156\xbf\xb6\x97}m\xe9[\xe0\xea\xd15\xb4\xff\x00\xf9\x14B\x0c'
...: .-.-.-.-.-.-.
...: SAVES THE SESSION      OK!
...: DERIVE KEY:
...: Salt: b'cookie-session'
...: Key: b'testing'
...: mac1: b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
...: mac2: b'\xd5\x8b\xd5+L\xedT7N\xa5\xba\xca\x0bj\xa5+\x0e\x03\xaft'
...: .-.-.-.-.-.-.
...: OPEN THE SESSION       OK!
...: DERIVE KEY:
...: Salt: b'cookie-session'
...: Key: b'testing'
...: mac1: b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
...: mac2: b'\xd5\x8b\xd5+L\xedT7N\xa5\xba\xca\x0bj\xa5+\x0e\x03\xaft'
...: .-.-.-.-.-.-.
...: SAVES THE SESSION      OK!
...: DERIVE KEY:
...: Salt: b'cookie-session'
...: Key: b'testing'
...: mac1: b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
...: mac2: b'\xd5\x8b\xd5+L\xedT7N\xa5\xba\xca\x0bj\xa5+\x0e\x03\xaft'
...: .-.-.-.-.-.-.
...: OPEN THE SESSION       OK!
...: DERIVE KEY:
...: Salt: b'cookie-session'
...: Key: b'testing'
...: mac1: b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
...: mac2: b'\xd5\x8b\xd5+L\xedT7N\xa5\xba\xca\x0bj\xa5+\x0e\x03\xaft'
...: .-.-.-.-.-.-.
...: SAVES THE SESSION      OK!
...: DERIVE KEY:
...: Salt: b'cookie-session'
...: Key: b'testing'
...: mac1: b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
...: mac2: b'\xd5\x8b\xd5+L\xedT7N\xa5\xba\xca\x0bj\xa5+\x0e\x03\xaft'
...: .-.-.-.-.-.-.
...: OPEN THE SESSION       NOT OKAY!!
...: DERIVE KEY:
...: Salt: b'cookie-session'
...: Key: b'testing'
...: mac1: b'D\xdaR}\xa0\xf2\x9awpP\xa0\x018b\xfcfH}\xcau'
...: mac2: b'\xd5\x8b\xd5+L\xedT7N\xa5\xba\xca\x0bj\xa5+\x0e\x03\xaft'
...: .-.-.-.-.-.-.
...: SAVES THE SESSION      OK!
...: DERIVE KEY:
...: Salt: b'cookie-session'
...: Key: b'testing'
...: mac1: b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
...: mac2: b'\xd5\x8b\xd5+L\xedT7N\xa5\xba\xca\x0bj\xa5+\x0e\x03\xaft'
...: .-.-.-.-.-.-.
...: OPEN THE SESSION       OK!
...: DERIVE KEY:
...: Salt: b'cookie-session'
...: Key: b'testing'
...: mac1: b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
...: mac2: b'\xd5\x8b\xd5+L\xedT7N\xa5\xba\xca\x0bj\xa5+\x0e\x03\xaft'
...: .-.-.-.-.-.-.
...: SAVES THE SESSION      OK!
...: DERIVE KEY:
...: Salt: b'cookie-session'
...: Key: b'testing'
...: mac1: b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
...: mac2: b'\xd5\x8b\xd5+L\xedT7N\xa5\xba\xca\x0bj\xa5+\x0e\x03\xaft'
...: .-.-.-.-.-.-.
...: OPEN THE SESSION       NOT OKAY!!
...: DERIVE KEY:
...: Salt: b'cookie-session'
...: Key: b'testing'
...: mac1: b'=\xcc\x01\xee"\x0ed\xde\xf4z\run\rMm\x98\xcb\x0e\xba'
...: mac2: b'\xd5\x8b\xd5+L\xedT7N\xa5\xba\xca\x0bj\xa5+\x0e\x03\xaft'
...: .-.-.-.-.-.-.
...: SAVES THE SESSION      OK!
...: DERIVE KEY:
...: Salt: b'cookie-session'
...: Key: b'testing'
...: mac1: b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
...: mac2: b'\xd5\x8b\xd5+L\xedT7N\xa5\xba\xca\x0bj\xa5+\x0e\x03\xaft'
...: .-.-.-.-.-.-.
...: OPEN THE SESSION       OK!
...: DERIVE KEY:
...: Salt: b'cookie-session'
...: Key: b'testing'
...: mac1: b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
...: mac2: b'\xd5\x8b\xd5+L\xedT7N\xa5\xba\xca\x0bj\xa5+\x0e\x03\xaft'
...: .-.-.-.-.-.-.
...: SAVES THE SESSION      OK!
...: DERIVE KEY:
...: Salt: b'cookie-session'
...: Key: b'testing'
...: mac1: b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
...: mac2: b'\xd5\x8b\xd5+L\xedT7N\xa5\xba\xca\x0bj\xa5+\x0e\x03\xaft'
...: .-.-.-.-.-.-.
```

I added the "OK!" and "NOT OKAY!" so that it is easier for you to see which executions went wrong.

(I also see that it, in this example, is not 60% fails. )

In the output above, Only the "Open session"-event failed. So i tried it again to see if it is only when saving the session, but it happens for Save-session also..

```
...: SAVES THE SESSION      NOT OK!   
...: DERIVE KEY:
...: Salt: b'cookie-session'
...: Key: b'testing'
...: mac1: b'\xc8D\xf0\x95\xc5R\x9f\xe3n\xc7\xa2 `7\xa9\xdb\xdd\xd8F\x85'
...: mac2: b'\xc8D\xf0\x95\xc5R\x9f\xe3n\xc7\xa2 `7\xa9\xdb\xdd\xd8F\x85'
```

I finally found a small example program that reproduces the error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

async_mode = "eventlet"

if async_mode is None:
    try:
        import eventlet
        async_mode = 'eventlet'
    except ImportError:
        pass

    if async_mode is None:
        try:
            from gevent import monkey
            async_mode = 'gevent'
        except ImportError:
            pass

    if async_mode is None:
        async_mode = 'threading'

    print('async_mode is ' + async_mode)

if async_mode == 'eventlet':
    import eventlet
    eventlet.monkey_patch()
elif async_mode == 'gevent':
    from gevent import monkey
    monkey.patch_all()

import hmac
import hashlib
import time
from threading import Thread
thread = None


def background_thread():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    error_mac = ""
    while True:
        error_mac = ""
        time.sleep(0.1)
        counter = 0
        for i in range(0, 40):
            time.sleep(0.001)
            mac = hmac.new(b'testing', digestmod=hashlib.sha1).digest() # == b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b':

            if not mac ==  b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b':
                counter = counter + 1
                error_mac = mac
        if error_mac:
            print("Example of the wrong hmacs calculated:")
            print(error_mac)
            print("--------------------------------------")
        print("{} - {}".format(time.time(), counter))

def index():
    global thread
    if thread is None:
        thread = Thread(target=background_thread)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    for i in range(0,40):
        print(hmac.new(b'testing', digestmod=hashlib.sha1).digest())
    thread.join()
    return "ok"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    index()
```

Usually if there is an error of the first 20 hashes (created by the main thread) also the second thread will get the wrong hash. If no error occur in the main thread, and the second thread outputs only timestsamp and zeros, then restart the program.

It async_mode is set to "threading" everything works fine. But when set to "gevent" or "eventlet" this error occur.

Output with error:

```
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
b'D\xb4V\r9$gy\xe1 \x13\xd8\xc4f\x93O\x9e\xfa\x02\xff'
Example of the wrong hmacs calculated:
b"\x19\xd2}YU\xfeyX\x87\xee\xf5\x96\x94\xc1'\xa3tP\xb3\x96"
--------------------------------------
1463462121.3955774 - 40
Example of the wrong hmacs calculated:
b"\x19\xd2}YU\xfeyX\x87\xee\xf5\x96\x94\xc1'\xa3tP\xb3\x96"
--------------------------------------
1463462121.6040413 - 40
Example of the wrong hmacs calculated:
b"\x19\xd2}YU\xfeyX\x87\xee\xf5\x96\x94\xc1'\xa3tP\xb3\x96"
--------------------------------------
1463462121.8342147 - 40
Example of the wrong hmacs calculated:
b"\x19\xd2}YU\xfeyX\x87\xee\xf5\x96\x94\xc1'\xa3tP\xb3\x96"
```

Output with no error:

```
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
b'j\xb6\xfc\x89\x1e\xef\xd3\xb7\x87C\xea(\xb1\x808\x11V\x1a|\x9b'
1463462453.3856905 - 0
1463462453.5910842 - 0
1463462453.8242626 - 0
1463462454.0677884 - 0
1463462454.2900438 - 0
1463462454.5460255 - 0
1463462454.7883186 - 0
```

(On my ubuntu machine, this example works perfeclty. It is only on the ARM7 device that we have this problem..)

Comment: Can you make a shorter *self-contained* example. You have a *method* with implicit `self` but I do not see a class definition anywhere!

Comment: Is it really that the HMAC is b0rken, or that you're initializing the secret many times?

Comment: Probably your Python is b0rken, or openssl is b0rken. Is it using OpenSSL on that platform?

Comment: what if you hardcode the salt and key into that code path, will you still get the wrong mac outputs?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well, the code above is from "itsdangerous.py" which I think is installed together with Flask. Yes it is openssl_sha1 that is used. I'm going to try with a hardcoded salt and key later. I don't know what is broken here. Im trying to figure it out :D

Comment: About the self-contained example. I did try the hmac out. and it works as it should. (10 threads x 1000 tries in parallell) I will try to create an example that uses itsdangerous.py.

Comment: I tried to hardcode both salt and secret key, without any success. Sometimes the first mac.digest() returns wrong, and second is OK, sometimes the other way around. And i also still can see some where both outputs is the same!

Comment: Hardcoded the "digestmod" to hashlib.sha1. Without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I changed the arguments to gevetn patch all:

```
...
elif async_mode == 'gevent':
    from gevent import monkey
    monkey.patch_all(ssl=False)
...
```

It seems to work.